# Is this metallic sound from Asus laptop normal?

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, asus-laptop

I have an 'Asus TUF Gaming FX505GT-BQ028 i7-9750H 16GB 512SSD' with a HDD Seagate Barracuda 1TB 2.5''. I have used the laptop only for 2 days, but from time to time, it sounds a metallic sound, and I don't know if it's something I should worry about. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R8MsB8Sn0aWNh8uZCpcbUkfKOQDd78nm/view?usp=sharing) I have a recording of the sound, although it is low, so it recommended to listen with headphones and high volume (the sound is at the end of the recording).
Moreover, I have check with windows `chkdsk` if there was any error in the SSD or HDD but there isn't any problem.

Thank you for your responses

Comment: Well, we need some more information about where exactly the sound comes from. The only thing I can say by listening to the audio clip is that I've had laptops in the past making weird noises but it could be a variety of reasons, such as thermal expansion etc..

Comment: Well, I'm not an expert, so I don't know exactly where the sound comes from. I can say that it comes from the interior of the laptop (it isn't a beep sound as in Windows), but I don't know the exact component, and I wouldn't like to open the laptop since it's still in guarantee.